# How to use your mobile as a USB webcam

Tags: usb, android, webcam, camera

I have already tried many of them but i want to switch between the different camera lenses (like wide angle, macro, telescopic) none of the apps seem to offer it accept for an ios app called ios camera which is available as plugin for obs but that is also not available for linux and i have an android phone i am looking for for something free but paid is also okay.

Comment: This site does not make software recommendations.

Comment: i had tried that too itd oes not support other cams only front and back

Comment: Maybe https://obs.ninja will help.

Comment: Thanks i will check